# Will Diablo 3 use Steam?

Tags: steam, diablo-iii

I'd like to use Steam to play Diablo III and track achievements. WIll it use Steam, and will it be available for download through Steam?

Comment: Why the downvote? The answer is mostly obvious, but I don't see a reason unless it's a duplicate, since there's always place for factual evidence as opposed to inference from past games.

Comment: @Fadeway I am not the one who downvoted it, but technically this should be closed because it fall in to the `Speculation of the future of the industry and of upcoming releases`, we don't know if Blizzard suddenly decided to use Steam, it is very unlikely but it could happen and I have seen no official statement to it.

Comment: @Blem I thought one month from release there would be some concrete information on where it will be available from. If the answer is "No" or "Not unless something changes", that's answer enough.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Diablo 3 will not use Steam or Steamworks: like all Blizzard games, it will use Battle.net. And while Blizzard has stopped short of saying it's a Battle.net digital exclusive sale, the [press release for the Diablo III release date](http://us.blizzard.com/en-us/company/press/pressreleases.html?id=4606414) states (emphasis mine):

> Starting that day, gamers with a thirst for fast-paced action and adventure will be able to purchase Diablo III at retailers throughout the United States, Canada, Europe, South Korea, Southeast Asia, Australia, New Zealand, and the regions of Taiwan, Hong Kong, and Macau. **In addition, gamers in the regions above as well as in Mexico, Argentina, Chile, and Brazil will be able to buy Diablo III digitally via Blizzard’s Battle.net® website.**

Given that Starcraft 2, Warcraft 3, and World of Warcraft are all Battle.net digital exclusives and are not available for purchase on Steam, it's unlikely Blizzard will offer Diablo 3 there.

Answer (score 1):

I guess not, because neither Starcraft 2 nor any other Blizzard game is on Steam. But you can buy it online from Blizzard's [Diablo 3 Battle.net Site](http://us.battle.net/d3/en), which is probably the reason why it isn't on Steam: why should they pay Steam if they have their own online shop?